# How to redirect localhost:3000 to a specific page in ruby on rails using netbeans as an IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I have Rails version 2.3.8.I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 as IDE. I want to redirect localhost:3000 to a specific page. i opened routes.rb file and uncommented the line

```
 map.root :controller => "Welcome"
```

I created a controller named Welcome and a view named index. I also deleted the default index file as suggested in some of the websites.However, the page is not getting redirected to new index page. What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your server is working.
Start your server and check for any errors are fired in the console
console is your friend!!!

Comment: the default port of rails apps is 3000. you can check it through this command 'lsof -i :3000'. a process should come up with details. However, if you want your application to run in a different port, try this command, 'rails s -p 4000'

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a specific page, delete the public/index.html file and then add to routes.rb ->

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Try to use command prompt, navigate to your folder and "rails s" to open your Server.

Comment: do i need to install ruby or redmine seperately??

Comment: No, just "rails s" in your folder, then in your browser go to http://localhost:3000/ and you should see your app. And the page should show you the one you defined in root :to =>

Comment: what do you mean by rail s in your folder??

Comment: C:\Users..........\Beginier application > rails s 
'rails is not recognizable as internal or external command, operable program or batch file'..........
THis is what happens when i type rails s in cmd

Comment: Oh... it seems you don't Have rails installed on your Computer -> http://railsinstaller.org/

Comment: But I have installed plugin for Ruby on Rails in my Netbeans.....Do I need Rails seperately??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33841/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-pratik-sharma)

Comment: @MiniJohn  
I have a question
why does view option not appear when we press Alt+Ctrl+g??
Do i have to add all of the views when i create a controller?? Can't I add views later??

Comment: If i understood that right, you want the views for a controller you gernerated. You can type rails g modelname:views